# Замена значений mysql из txt-файла

Tags: php, mysql, поиск, замена

Поиск и замена средствами php и mysql.

Условия поиска такие как указаны без двусмысленностей и вариаций (т.е. искать вхождение в поле таблицы), а значения 160, 170, 180 и т.д. выкушены предварительно (другими методами) из aaa160bbb и т.д., и всё это нужно заменить на одно значение.

Пояснение: если 160 найдется тут aaa160bbb или тут aaa1600000bbb - это то, что нам и нужно.

Есть файл на хостинге file.txt со значениями

```
160
170
180
```

В базе mysqldb в таблице mytable в поле speed такие данные

```
aaa160bbb
ccc170ddd
eee180fff
```

Сделать поиск и замену ВХОЖДЕНИЙ значений из файла txt на 11111 чтобы получилось так

```
aaa11111bbb
ccc11111ddd
eee11111fff
```

Помогите сделать?!
Не умрет ли обычный хостинг во время выполнения?
В txt может быть несколько десятков тысяч значений, т.е. 10 000+

Comment: У вас задача подозрительно странная. Скорее всего вам надо пересматривать архитектуру базы, раз такие задачи появляются. В общем виде, если у вас вокруг цифр в таблице не цифры, я бы предложил создать еще колонку или другую таблицу в которую выделить цифры из строк, потом построить индекс по этому полю и после этого уже искать записи по данным из файла

Comment: а если будет `aaa1600bbb`, а в файле есть число 160 - менять надо? Умрет хостинг или нет только тесты покажут, мы может только сказать что возможно (т.е. еще не факт) ему будет не сладко. Но в таком случае, обновлять можно частями, т.е. обновили 1К записей - сделали паузу, обновили еще одну партию - опять пауза и т.д. Но чтобы так не извращаться - лучше переделать используемый подход, хотя бы переделать структуру БД

Comment: Переделывание структуры базы исключено, нужна просто замена

Comment: Но все-таки вопрос ВОРОНа остается: "а если будет aaa1600bbb, а в файле есть число 160 - менять надо?" Плюс еще вопросы: о каком кол-ве значений мы говорим (160, 170, 180 до.... ? ) "10 000, 20, 30+" - это столько в тхт файле или в базе?

Comment: Если в файле будет `aaa1600bbb`, а заменить надо `160`, то после замены получится `aaa11110bbb`. Это правильно? или так НЕ надо?

Comment: Это правильно. Заменять надо.

Comment: ок, менять надо, а если там будет 160 и 1600? Что должно быть в итоге? Если заменим сначала 160, то в итоге у нас будет `aaa111110bbb`, а если сначала заменим 1600, то получим уже `aaa11111bbb`, т.е. совсем другой результат. А если в файле будет, например, 10, 160, а в базе есть `aaa16000bbb` - что должно быть? По идее только 160 надо заменить, т.е. получить `aaa1111100bbb`, но тогда у нас появилась строка с 10 - ее надо менять или нет? Допустим, надо. Заменяем, получили `aaa1111111110bbb` - опять 10 есть! А если в файле будет 11? Мы так бесконечно менять можем. Что делать в этих случаях?

Comment: Изначально значения типа aaa160bbb находятся в xml, когда все уже в базе, то поздно дергаться и менять в xml. Так вот значения для файла txt берутся из xml и получается так, что я специально подбираю значения типа 160, 170, 180 и .... (шаманю в офисных программах) так, чтобы не было таких вариантов как вы указали. Т.е в txt файле только уникальные значения, которые в одной ячейке таблицы (базы mysql) можут встретиться только 1 раз, а в целом в поле таблицы могут встретиться несколько раз, т.е. может быть найдено несколько 160 в aaa160bbb, vvvv160fff, nnn160mmm и т.д. 160 и 1600 такого не будет